# C#: Accessing files added to project folder

Tags: c#

how can i access files I've included in the project folder in Visual C# Windows Application... I've created a folder in the solution and I've added some files. Now, My problem is how to access them?

In ASP.NET C# there is ResolveUrl / Url.Content... etc... In Visual C#? what should i do?

Comment: I.E: I want to access files from a folder which contains files like images, or DLL files.. etc... I did not use resources folder into it.

Comment: thanks....but 
I've got it!!! here's the code.. 

> System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("../../xulrunner/");

Answer (score 8):

In the properties of those files you could set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer` and so everytime you run the application they will be copied to the `bin/Debug` folder alongside with the executable and in your application you could access them as relative files: `File.ReadAllText("myfile.txt");`:

[image]

Comment: thanks....but 
I've got it!!! here's the code.. 

> System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("../../xulrunner/");

Comment: @Roberto Becher, access those files as if they was in the same folder:  `File.ReadAllText("myfile.txt")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` method to get the current working directory of your application is running in. For more details you can refer to MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks....but 
I've got it!!! here's the code.. 

> System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("../../xulrunner/");

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of files they are, but you may find that a "Resources file" does what you want. Add one of these to your project and then add your existing files to it as resources. You can then access these resources as properties of the resource type.

E.g.

1. add resources file named Resources.resx)
2. add a text file to the resources file named "Foo.txt"

   var foo = Resources.Foo;

Answer (score 0):

use Server.MapPath

sample:

```
    string pathToFiles = Server.MapPath("~/ResourceFiles");
    string templateFile = pathToFiles + "/MyFileTemplate.xlsx";
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(templateFile))
```

{
}